# Sphinx automodule to show module name?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I've used `.. automodule:: mypath.mymodule` in my documentation. I wanted the plain module docstring with no other information for members. The module docstring appears, however no indication of the name of the module and no special paragraph formatting.

Is there a standard way to include the name of the actual module and maybe emphasis that particular paragraph as to distinguish it from normal text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that the "standard" way is to add a heading with the module name:

```
mypath.mymodule
===============

.. automodule:: mypath.mymodule
```

Examples from some packages (click on "Show Source" to see the reST markup):

- Celery: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.events.html
- PyMongo: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/index.html
- matplotlib: http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html

Comment: The problem is that there would be no “Show source” link next to module name, which would be convenient to have. I guess it's a decision made by Sphinx developers, or a bug.